# class is not abstract and does not override abstract method java error TIcTacToe game

Tags: java, swing

For a project I have to make a tictactoe game. However I'm having a problem with using ActionListener. It brings up the error that class is not abstract and does not override abstract method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JFrame gFrame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
    private JButton [][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
    private JButton reset = new JButton("New Game");


public GameGUI() {
    super("TicTacToe");
    gFrame.setSize(500,380);
    gFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gFrame.setVisible(true);
    gFrame.setResizable(false);
    gameBoard();
}

// Set everything into the actual game board
private void gameBoard() {
  JPanel mPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel options = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel game = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));               

  gFrame.add(mPanel);                                       

  mPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,425));
  options.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));                    
  game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

  mPanel.add(options, BorderLayout.NORTH);                          
  mPanel.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  options.add(reset, BorderLayout.NORTH);


for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

     buttons[i][j] = new JButton();                
     buttons[i][j].setText("");
     buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);
     buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);

     game.add(buttons[i][j]);  
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure how to go about and fix this so any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly new to Java so please excuse if the code is not great.

Comment: GameGUI implements the ActionListener interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) but doesn't implement the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method.

Comment: Not what you asked, but please don't use asterisks in your import statements. They can [cause your code to fail unexpectedly](http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html).

Comment: Oh right thanks, I know its off topic but how would I go about implementing all the logic in a separate class such as GameLogic, and only have the gui update when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code,

```
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
```

you're saying that a `GameGui` object should respond when one of the buttons is clicked.  But you haven't specified *how* it will respond.  In other words, you need to write a method that contains the code that you want to run when a button is clicked.

The first line of that method should be

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

because that's the way the method has been declared in the [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface.  When you wrote `implements ActionListener` in the declaration of your class, you promised to provide implementations of all the methods listed in the [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface.  Fortunately, there's only one such method, but you *do* need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend an abstract class or implement an interface, you need to complete the concrete class definition by providing definition to all those inherited abstract functions.

In this case, you are missing definition to the following method which is declared in ActionListener interface

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

Comment: Oh right thanks, I know its off topic but how would I go about implementing all the logic in a separate class such as GameLogic, and only have the gui update when needed?